Swift - Can someone explain me what does _ do?
    class Coordinator:NSObject, CountryPickerDelegate{
        var parent: CountryPickerUI
        
        init(_ parent: CountryPickerUI) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }

I'm having a hard time understanding swift.

what does the _ besides parent mean?

What does NSObject, CountryPickerDelegate do? does it mean coordinator class should be NSObj and CountryPickerDelegate?


Please explain.

Please see the Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names section in the Swift book.

See Omitting parameters in a section under HangarRash's above: "If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that parameter."

To answer you 2nd question: NSObject is a class provided by the Foundation framework in Swift. It is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. The Coordinator class is not required to be both an NSObject and a CountryPickerDelegate.
